# Почему последний аргумент функции встает на первое место?

Tags: json, http, lua

Для наглядности просто прикреплю два скрина, по ним будет понятнее.

На скриншотах запрос и ответ от сервера.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее покажу сам код: LUA

```
function MTAPaymentData(user, amount)
    return ("user = "..tostring(user).."   |   amount = "..tostring(amount))
end
```

Comment: мало данных, может уже сюда `MTAPaymentData(user, amount)` приходит так, такие вопросы на месте решаются , тут толку не будет.

Comment: у вас проблема не с функцией (очевидно же), а с ее вызовом

Answer (score 1):

В ссылке пробелы оставлять нельзя)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]